# Sharing common code between derived classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm having trouble when trying to share common code between derived classes in the below example:

```
class BaseWrite {
    public:
    virtual void setup() {}
};

class Write : public BaseWrite {
    public:
    void show() {
        cout << "Show Write" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "print Write" << endl;
    }    
};

class CompWrite : public Write {
    public:
    void compFunc() {
        cout << "compFunc details" << endl;
    }
};

//These below "Special" classes are in a separate file and are conditionally included while building the project

class SpecialWrite : public Write {
    public:
    void setup() override {
        cout << "print SpecialWrite setup()" << endl;
    }
};

class SpecialCompWrite : public CompWrite {
    public:
    //any common functions
};
```

In the above example, a `CompWrite` (or `SpecialCompWrite`) object should be able to access all the functions of `Write` class and also the `setup()` implementation that is being overridden in `SpecialWrite` class.

The constraint is, I cannot move up the `setup` function from `SpecialWrite` class to the `Write` class or `BaseWrite` class. And if it helps the context, the "Special*" classes are in a separate file and are conditionally included while building the project.

One way is I can simply override the `setup` function in `SpecialCompWrite` class as well and copy the code from `SpecialWrite` class. But I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: ``I cannot move up the setup function from SpecialWrite class to the Write class or BaseWrite class.`` Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CompWrite` has access to all public functions in `SpecialWrite` then a multiple inheritance could solve the problem, but both classes inherit from `Write` so the inheritances must be changed to virtual, the `CompWrite` class will look like:

```
class CompWrite : public Write, public SpecialWrite {
```

If the `setup()` function is the only function that needs to be accessible maybe a new class that both `SpecialWrite` and `CompWrite` inherit could solve it.

```
class SetupWrite : public Write {
    public:
    void setup() override {
        cout << "print SpecialWrite setup()" << endl;
    }
};

...

class CompWrite : public SetupWrite {
    public:
    void compFunc() {
        cout << "compFunc details" << endl;
    }
};

...

class SpecialWrite : public SetupWrite {
    public:
    // Other functions
};
```